# HTML/CSS hover one object to make another change its attribute

Tags: html, css

Hello and thank you all for taking a look in my problem: Here what i have :

```css
#div1 {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#div2 {
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Now i wanna change div2's background into green by hovering div1, how do i do this only with css?

**Update**: i have a same question but another story:

--HTML--

```
<div id="div1"></div>

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

--HTML--

--CSS--

```
#div1 {
      background: red;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
    }

    #div2 {
      background: blue;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
    }

    #wrapper{
      width:500px;
      height:500px;
    }
```

--CSS--

Figured :

```
#div1:hover + #wrapper #div2{
background:green;}
```

for some reason idk why #div1:hover + #div2 doesnt work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with the `+` css selector, which selects elements directly after the current element

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#div1:hover+#div2 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Comment: i have updated another question, if ur free pls have a look

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. It is important though that you keep the HTML structure as it is.

```css
#div1 {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#div2 {
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#div1:hover+#div2 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Comment: i have updated another question, if ur free pls have a look